# What happened to Viserion in Season 7?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the end of season 7, Daenerys's dragon, Viserion,

> died and the Night King raised it. Did he raise the dragon as a [White Walker](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Others) or just [an ordinary soldier](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wights) in the Army of the Dead?

Does it make any difference in that case?

Comment: I also answered this over on [movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/79288/45378).

Comment: I've tried to make the title less of a spoiler but it's a bit unclear now, if anyone has a better idea for one, please edit it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With the release of the official script for Episode 7 we see that he is indeed a White <s>Walker</s> Flyer.

> *A massive chunk of the Wall breaks free ahead of Tormund. The ice dragon glides away, and we get our first clear look at him, and at the Night King on his back. **He's done the same thing to Viserion that he did to Craster's sons. Only those were babies, and this is a dragon.***
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf" - Official script</sub>

A White Walker is created by the Night King placing his hand on the subject, like with Craster's baby boys:

[image: Craster's newborn baby being transformed into a White Walker by having the Night King touch him]
<sup>Craster's newborn baby being transformed into a White Walker by having the Night King touch him, "Oathkeeper" (*Game of Thrones*, S04E04)</sup>

Then compare the eyes of the White <s>Walker</s> Crawler to the wight's eyes below.

[image: A wight]
<sup>A wight which I believe is from Hardhome, "Hardhome" (*Game of Thrones*, S05E08)</sup>

As you can see a wights eyes are a lot cloudier than the sharp blue of a White Walkers.

Now compare those of Viserion's:

[image: Viserion opens his eyes after the Nights King touches him]
<sup>Viserion opens his eyes after the Nights King touches him, "Beyond the Wall" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E06)</sup>

As you can see his eyes more closely resemble a White Walker than a wight.

Comment: Official script, page 62: https://www.emmys.com/sites/default/files/collateral/118%20Game%20Of%20Thrones%20-%20The%20Dragon%20and%20the%20Wolf.pdf

Comment: This is new information to me. Thought he was just a Wight. Being a white flyer he has consciousness & can take action on his own

Comment: Ugh, this makes no sense.  I mean, I don't doubt this is the right answer, I'm just griping that the writers' choice to do this doesn't fit with the lore.  Corpses don't become white walkers, living babies do.  Unless they're claiming Viserion somehow survived the ice lance, the crash into the frozen water, and hours or days of submersion...

Comment: @Paul your trying to claim total knowledge from the tidbits of knowledge we get about the White Walkers. Just because we’ve only seen living babies become White Walkers doesn’t mean dead things can’t. Also worth noting that dragons are magical creatures and so are a different case to humans.

Comment: I’m not trying to claim perfect knowledge @TheLethalCarrot, I’m complaining that this breaks verisimilitude for me. Yes, anything can be explained by magic, but good stories stay internally consistent and I don’t believe this is.

Comment: Benioff has said that ["themes are for eighth-grade book reports"](http://grantland.com/features/the-return-hbo-game-thrones/). I wonder if they think consistency is too.

Comment: @Paul My point was that we know very little about the White Walkers and their magic and so every time we see them do something it breaks the previous lore of what we knew. Raising Viserion was no exception to this, it doesn't match with what we've seen before because we've never seen something like it before. Trying to fit it to what we've seen before won't work because of this.

Comment: @Paul “Corpses don't become white walkers, living babies do”. When did the show say *only* living babies do? Does it have to explicitly lay out complete rules every time it shows you something?