# Why do only some White Walkers shatter into ice chips?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I noticed some "White Walkers" break into ice chips and others do not; some only fall down and are immobile.  Why is that?

Answer (score 56):

### White Walkers "shatter" and Wights fall down.

[image]

White Walkers (also known as Others in the books) are inhuman beings with mystic powers. They are not dead but instead are a sort of magical humanoid life form. White Walkers have the ability to turn dead and decomposed bodies into wights. "Wight" is a catch-all term for the reanimated corpses of humans. Thus, only "some White Walkers" shatter into chips, because the ones that don't are not White Walkers.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also the corpses of giants, horses

Comment: Wasn't the dragon a wight, yet it shattered?

Comment: The dragon collapsed, I don't think it shattered.

Comment: Dragon shattered after TNK got killed

Comment: @CodeMoose the dragon [wasn't a wight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/209638/what-happened-to-viserion-in-season-7)

Comment: The Night King and the White Walkers have always shattered like Swarovski crystal when they die and there is no corpse remaining afterward.  Just a pile of ice crystals. Wights do not shatter like that, they simply fall to the ground and there is an obvious corpse remaining.  Sometimes parts will fall off when they die, especially if the wight was already damaged or was just a skeleton held together only by the magic that animated it.  When the dragon died, it absolutely did NOT shatter into ice crystals.  There was obviously a dead dragon on the ground in front of Jon Snow.

Comment: [Scene proof](https://youtu.be/VNcLtsdwkE8?t=188) that Viserion didn't shatter

Comment: Of course, dragons are kind of magical, so maybe the rules are different for them somehow. Sure looks like a wight to me though.

Comment: I reject the notion that Viserion wasn't a wight. No other explanation makes sense. He was dead when he was raised. He's definitely a wight. The blue eyes can be explained by the dragon having innate magic (which we know dragons do). (FWIW I don't care what's in the script. It's clear that most of the writers don't even understand their own universe. What's on screen is *the only canon*.)

Comment: @only_pro All the wights have blue eyes - that seems like a good explanation for why Viserion would also.

Comment: @ToddWilcox It's not strong enough of a reason for me. The show has been inconsistent about plenty of things in the past. It seems that whether the entity was *alive* when "turned" is what determines whether it becomes a WW. Otherwise, why wouldn't the NK just turn every dead body into a WW instead of a wight? Plus, when Viserion "died" for the final time, he didn't shatter. Those two points combined make for a stronger case that he's a wight instead of a WW.